# Use HTTPS for snippets because some features are HTTPS only

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, ssl

Many features of the browsers are starting to [require HTTPS](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins) which means they don't work on Stack Overflow snippets. Please consider using HTTPS for Stack Overflow snippets.

I recently tried to answer a question about using the mic in HTML5/JavaScript. I tried to use a snippet but Chrome gave an error because the snippet was not HTTPS so I had to post the example offsite.

Comment: Better solution: use HTTPS for the _entire site_, including snippets.

Comment: @JonasCz it's a work in progress https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is there a roadmap or similar for it? (Considering the post is 3 years old.) Is letsencrypt.org or a similar solution to automate fetching of certs per domain? .

Comment: @kb We're going to be switching to the *.meta.stackexchange.com path scheme, and it's actively being worked on. We were waiting for the new CDN to go live before working on the structure change.

Comment: It's the year of <s>linux on the desktop<s> stack overflow respecting its users privacy!

Comment: This strikes me as rather contrary to the https promise.  You'd expect the certificate to prove where the code comes from.  On a site that accepts code from *anybody* without any proof of identity at all, isn't that a rather gross violation?  Would you *want* to click the Run Snippet button when you have no real idea what it does and requires https to do something?  Bad idea.

Comment: What Hans said. _Please_ don't do this. I fear there's a "ohmergerd HTTPS!!!11" fad going on at the moment where people are setting up HTTPS left right and centre without actually applying any thought to the question of whether they _should_ be doing so. Because it's more "secure", right? Sigh.

Comment: @HansPassant: I disagree.  These are clearly marked as user-generated content.  The only requirement you have to follow to get an HTTPS certificate is don't share your private key.  Everything else is a matter of good (or bad) web design.  So either you allow user-generated scripts to run, or you don't.  But HTTPS is totally orthogonal to that decision.

Comment: Note that HTTPS-only features actually require the entire context to be secure: so not only must the snippets be delivered via HTTPS, but the page itself must be. (Without this restriction, the insecure remainder of the page could be MITMed to manipulate and/or eavesdrop on the "secure" snippet.) So you might as well incorporate @JonasCz's comment into your question: it's not just a "better solution", but rather, it's actually necessary for what you want.

Comment: StackOverflow has worked for years without executable snippets, and continues to work with plain code listings in any non-web language. Your example code should speak for itself, not just demonstrate to be working.

Comment: or just use cloudflare's SSL? with some performance degration ...

Comment: FYI, **Stack Snippets are already available over HTTPS**; you get the HTTPS version just as long as the containing page is also loaded over HTTPS. This also means that its a little late to say we should all *PANIC* because user-created code is loaded over HTTPS.

Comment: @Bergi, I guess you're arguing we should get rid of snippets? Working code is better than non-working code. Snippets prove it works, no room for typos or forgetting something. Arguably better than static text. Even better if it stops working it is more likely to be noticed when someone runs the snippet and then fixed, unlike static text which many have never run in the first place.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit of course it's more secure. My coworker not being able to sniff on my traffic is a pretty good bump in security. Why the snarkiness?

Comment: @rr-: Read Hans's comment to find out the problem with that. You're free to disagree but don't fling around accusations, please.

Comment: Can we stop discussion if it's secure or not? The whole FR is about features that are disabled by the client if it's not HTTPS.

Comment: @gman: No, I'm not against snippets (and not against HTTPS either), I'm arguing with "*…so I had to post the example offsite*", which isn't really necessary for a good answer with a good example.  I think it's just a minor nuisance if the very few secure-only features don't work in snippets, the majority of answers on SO (with non-web languages) has the same problem, and the majority of web answers still works as snippets.
Also I hope (it's not clear from the wording) you didn't post the example *only* offsite, as that would be against our good practices.

Comment: @Bergi, ok, maybe I should make it clear the specific issue being answered was that something wasn't working for the questioner. So posting something that provably worked was important to the answer as in "this worked for me, click here to see it works for you too". Yes I could have posted sample code but then we'd be back to checking his code was exactly the same as mine in every possible way. My code was actually the same as the questioner's except moving it to an HTTPS hosted site just incase his non-SO version of the code was on HTTP.

Comment: @HansPassant Snippets are served from `stacksnippets.net`, so snippets can't steal things like SO login cookies. They also use `<iframe sandbox>`, so unless I'm badly misunderstanding the spec, browsers supporting `sandbox` will treat each iframe on each page load [as if it was from a unique origin](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/origin-0.html#sandboxOrigin). Since browsers only treat *origins the user has previously trusted* as trustworthy - rather sensibly, since anyone can get a HTTPS certificate - snippets will never be able to *persist* things like microphone permissions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: *“I fear there's a […] fad going on at the moment where people are setting up HTTPS […] without actually applying any thought to the question of whether they should be doing so.”* With very few exceptions, they should always be doing so. This is not one of those exceptions. *“Because it's more "secure", right?”* Yes, that’s why.